# Go Channel and go routine with pointer variables all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go

I spend my evening looking at how to fix this error but I haven't succeeded. When I run the program I have the following error : "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". I understand this is because the main program is exited before the routine has the possibility to do its tasks and I thought using sync.WaitGroup would help but not really :/

I want to set a number of routine and use channels to send urls in order to check http status code. I want to limit the number of concurrency call to a website. I've followed examples doing the same thing with string instead of struct and it worked.

Any help would be well appreciated :)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    numPollers = 2                // number of Poller goroutines to launch
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://blog.golang.org/",
    "http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr",
    "https://gobyexample.com/",
}

// Resource represents an HTTP URL to be polled by this program.
type Resource struct {
    url      string
}

func Poller(in <-chan *Resource, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //defer wg.Done()
    for r := range in {
        fmt.Printf("Finished: %v - %v\n", r.url, time.Now())
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    pending := make(chan *Resource)

    wg.Add(len(urls))

    go Poller(pending, &wg)

    go func() {
        for _, url := range urls {
            wg.Add(1)
            fmt.Println("SENT > Pending url " + url)
            pending <- &Resource{url: url}
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Finished all goroutines: %v\n", time.Now())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/B-HSiDo2Qg

Comment: in the future when you have a blocking problem, you can send your process a `SIGQUIT` to print a stack trace which will show you where all goroutines are waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have too many calls to `wg.Add()`. You call that once for each goroutine you're running. See http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup. Second, you didn't close the channel after you were done writing to it. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const (
    numPollers = 2                // number of Poller goroutines to launch
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://www.google.com/",
    "http://golang.org/",
    "http://blog.golang.org/",
    "http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr",
    "https://gobyexample.com/",
}

// Resource represents an HTTP URL to be polled by this program.
type Resource struct {
    url      string
}

func Poller(in <-chan *Resource, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for r := range in {
        fmt.Printf("Finished: %v - %v\n", r.url, time.Now())
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    pending := make(chan *Resource)

    wg.Add(2)

    go Poller(pending, &wg)

    go func() {
        defer close(pending)
        defer wg.Done()
        for _, url := range urls {
            fmt.Println("SENT > Pending url " + url)
            pending <- &Resource{url: url}
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Finished all goroutines: %v\n", time.Now())
}
```

and https://play.golang.org/p/ucUlZEZMZM

Comment: Also, use defer for wg.Done(). eg. defer func(){ wg.Done()}

Comment: Instead of using two defer lines, it would be better to use one function. defer func(){ close(pending); wg.Done()}. something like this https://play.golang.org/p/n-dHABOoZy

Comment: Hmm, I like to follow Go's standard libs way of writing code, and I haven't seen code blocks which have multiple defer statements. As for technical aspect, I am not sure how it may or may not effect the code.

Comment: Well, the example at http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover uses multiple defer statements, although that's a different use case. Other than that, I don't think I've seen an official example either way.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I wasn't that far! The second wg.Add(1) when iterating over the urls slice was a try that I forgot to remove when posting here, I was aware that it wasn't needed. I don't understand why I should run "defer wg.Done()" twice in the program, it make sense in the Poller function but not in the main ?

Comment: @JulienD Defer is just a neater way of writing it. It will always run right before returning. If you expand your code with multiple exits for a goroutine, you'd need either a `wg.Done()` at each exit, or just the single deferred call. It behaves the same either way, so it's your choice which is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for you precisions, I played a bit more with channels yesterday and now I understand how it works. My main problem was that I misunderstood when to add a waigrout, I thought it was on each loop but it's by launched routines.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close channel, and your wait group is too long. This works for me: https://play.golang.org/p/yasIzaCbmQ